# How to edit multiple objects with one button? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have a table in which I show data that I get from my api. In my `.ts` component I do this to be able to access the data from my service, for this I do this.

```
getBloques() {
    this.configuracioncvService.getBloques()
      .subscribe(res => {
        let bloquesOrdenados = _.orderBy(res,['ordenCompleto'], ['asc'])
        this.configuracioncvService.bloques = bloquesOrdenados;
        console.log('BLOQUESRESTAPI', bloquesOrdenados)
      })
  }
```

In my service I have this:

```
getBloques() {
    return this.http.get<Bloque[]>(this.URL_BLOQUES);
}
```

And in my `html` to show this data I do this:

```
 <table class="table" id="tabla">
      <thead>
           <tr class="d-flex">
                <th class="col-3">Bloque</th>
                <th class="col-3">Orden</th>
                <th class="col-3">Guardar</th>
                <th class="col-3">Ingresar a Bloque</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            <tr class="d-flex" *ngFor="let bloque of configuracioncvService.bloques">
                 <td class="col-md-3">{{bloque.nombre}}</td>
                 <td class="col-md-3">
                      <mat-form-field>
                           <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Orden" [value]="bloque.ordenCompleto" [(ngModel)]="bloque.ordenCompleto">                                             
                      </mat-form-field>
                 </td>
                 <td class="col-md-3">
                      <button class="btn btn-secundary" (click)="editBloque(bloque)">
                           <i class="material-icons">save</i>
                      </button>
                 </td>
                 <td class="col-md-3">
                      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/bloque-completo/', bloque.nombre]">
                           <i class="material-icons">east</i>
                      </button>
                 </td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
 </table>
```

I show the data in the table, and in that table I have an input so that the value of the order column can be edited, my method to edit is this

```
editBloque(bloque: Bloque){
    this.configuracioncvService.putBloque(bloque).subscribe(res =>{
          console.log('editado', res)
      });
 }
```

Everything works for me correctly, the "problem" I have is that in my html for each object I have a button, so every time I change a data, I have to click on the button for this data to be edited, as in this image it is as I currently have.
[image: current item action layout]

My question is how can I make a single button that edits all the objects without having to save one by one as I have it now. What I'm looking to get is something like this.
[image: Expected single action button]

EDIT:

I have tried with formArray and save the form values ​​in an array, but I don't know how to loop through the array and edit.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-ngxxam?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This is fairly straight forward, just iterate the `this.configuracioncvService.bloques` and save the changes for each one. Try it out first by creating a function and hook it up to the new button. Update your post with the new button action script if you are still stuck.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Thanks for the reply. But the truth is I don't understand how I can do it

Comment: It's hard for us to understand exactly which area you need help with if you haven't tried, meaning this becomes very open ended and opinionated. This is "hello world" stuff, Start with the button, can you place it on the screen where you want it (pure HTML), then bind it to a call back method, can you write a "hello world" entry to the logs or raise an alert dialog from the button call back. Once you have gone that far, we can answer your specific question, but to include all that in a response to this question will make the solution less useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of another user I was able to achieve it this way using the ngModel and linking each input with a property of the object. In my `html`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let bloque of bloques">
  <input [(ngModel)]="bloque.nombre" disabled>
  <input [(ngModel)]="bloque.ordenCompleto">
</ng-container>
<br>
<button (click)="guardar()">
Guardar
</button>
```

In `.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent {

  bloques = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nombre: 'Articulos',
      ordenCompleto: 2,
      ordenResumido: 2,
      ordenPersonalizable: 2
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      nombre: 'Libros',
      ordenCompleto: 1,
      ordenResumido: 1,
      ordenPersonalizable: 1
    }
  ];

  bloquesOriginal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.bloques))

  guardar(){

    // iterate each of the blocks

   this.bloques.forEach(bloque => {

    let bloqueOriginal = this.bloquesOriginal.find(b => b.id == bloque.id)
    if(bloqueOriginal.ordenCompleto == bloque.ordenCompleto) return


    // if the block was modified proceed to save ito


    // this.configuracioncvService.putBloque(bloque).subscribe(res =>{
    //   console.log('editado', res)
    // });
   })

  }
}
```